# Why are my imported components not being used in react?

Tags: reactjs, backend

**header.js**

```
function header(){
    return(<div className="header"><header><h1>Header Content</h1></header></div>);
}
export default header;
```

**footer.js**

```
function footer(){
    return(<div className="footer"><footer>copyright 2022-23</footer></div>)
}
export default footer;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import header from './header';
import footer from './footer';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div><header/></div>
      <div><footer/></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Why are the imported components not being called?

I want to display the content of the `header.js` and `footer.js` files in `App.js` but it is saying that the `header` and `footer` variables are unused in the `App.js` file.

Answer (score 3):

In JSX, components must start with a capital letter. When you are using the `<header />` and `<footer />` tags, they are being interpreted as those html elements. To fix it, rename your `header` and `footer` components to `Header` and `Footer` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

In React Component names should be written with Capital letters

Header Component

```
function Header(){
    return(
     <div className="header">
       <header>
         <h1>Header Content</h1>
       </header>
     </div>);
}
export default Header;
```

Footer Component

```
function Footer(){
    return(
      <div className="footer">
        <footer>copyright 2022-23</footer>
      </div>)
}
export default Footer;
```

App Component

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './header';
import Footer from './footer';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Header/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're **importing components,** you need to **capitalize the component names** because React treats **lowercase names as regular HTML elements**.

**Rename your components :**

1. header.js >> Header.js
2. footer.js >> Footer.js

**replace in your code** :

1. function header() >> function Header()
2. function footer() >> function Footer()
3. export default header >> export default Header;
4. export default footer >> export default Footer;
5. import header from './header' >> import Header from './Header'
6. import header from './header' >> import Footer from './Footer'

Finally, use Header and Footer in your app.js

For more clear please have a look at [HTML header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header/)  and
[User Defined Components Must Be Capitalized](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)